# Matrix singularity issues with gaussian variogram

Tags: normal-distribution, variogram

I have defined my gaussian variogram like this

$r(h) = \text{nugget} + \text{partial_sill}\cdot(1 - \exp(-\frac{3h^2}{\text{range}^2}))$

I set nugget = 0.1343
partial_sill = 0.3125
range = 19.8642

I tried to create a variogram for a spatial grid of size 5x5, meaning for each of the location in the 5x5 grid, I calculated the value of the variogram with distance equal to its distance to the other locations in the grid.

So I had a matrix of size 25x25. However, this matrix is not positive definite and is singular. How can I remedy this issue with gaussian variogram?

Comment: What values of $h$ do your 25 distance values take?

Comment: It's just euclidean distance. I have the grid of size 5x5 a total of 25 locations. So the locations are like (1,1)(1,2)...(1,5)(2,1)... and so on the coordinates, I should say

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  An SVD of the matrix has singular values ranging from $3.68$ down to $0.1343$ and so obviously is positive definite.  Are you sure you have implemented the nugget correctly? By definition it is zero when $h=0$ and otherwise equals $0.1343$ for $h\gt 0$.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure but in that case the diagonal element is zero isn't it.

Comment: That is correct: instead of "nugget" in your formula you should write nugget$(h)$ to indicate that the value is $0$ when $h=0$ and otherwise equals $0.1343$. Because the Gaussian model is $0$ when $h=0$, that makes all diagonal elements $0$.

Comment: @whuber. I think you can answer my second question as well. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66823/issues-with-ordinary-kriging. I am running into similar issues. It may be some misunderstanding like in this case

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a circumstance that could not be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using power 2, try using 1.99.

Check out the similar solution to a question I posed along those same lines

[Prior selection for Gaussian Processes (GP)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65493/prior-selection-for-gaussian-processes-gp)